# How to convert single record row to column using in ORACLE Select statement with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to show the column names in the front side. That columns based on the condition satisfied in the select statement which is in the column have the value that column I need as one record. for that I am trying to writing the DB query. Could you please help on this query generating

[image: Current Table]

[image: Result Expected through DB script]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpivot with additional condition; lines #1 - 4 represent sample data (you have that, so your query begins at line #5):

```
SQL> with test (id, emp_name, is_maths_passed, is_science_passed, is_social_passed) as
  2    (select 123, 'Robert', 'YES', 'NO' , 'YES' from dual union all
  3     select 345, 'Devid' , 'NO' , 'YES', 'YES' from dual
  4    )
  5  select code, passed
  6  from (select * from (select * from test where id = &par_id)
  7        unpivot (passed
  8                 for code
  9                 in (is_maths_passed   as 'is_maths_passed',
 10                     is_science_passed as 'is_science_passed',
 11                     is_social_passed  as 'is_social_passed'
 12                    )
 13                )
 14       )
 15  where passed = 'YES';
Enter value for par_id: 123

CODE              PAS
----------------- ---
is_maths_passed   YES
is_social_passed  YES

SQL> /
Enter value for par_id: 345

CODE              PAS
----------------- ---
is_science_passed YES
is_social_passed  YES

SQL>
```